# How can I add a .php page to my Wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add a .php page to my Wordpress page? I already have a theme in which I want to integrate the php page. How can I do that?

Comment: Refer this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-wp-page-permalinks/ also you can check this https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#pathinfo-almost-pretty

Answer (score 2):

**1. Add WordPress template file and create WordPress page from it**

This is probably the best and simplest way of getting what you want... You need to create a template file and then make a WordPress page that uses that template [as found here](https://phppot.com/wordpress/add-php-page-in-wordpress/).  This way the new page can be found through the WordPress back-end and is therefore somewhat maintainable.

**2. Create custom PHP page through child theme's functions.php file**

Another valid option would be to create a [child theme](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme) and use code something like the following in the functions.php file (this sample taken and modified from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178588/i-want-to-create-a-custom-slug-in-wordpress-and-output-json-how-do-i-do-this/178596)):

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query){
    global $wp;

    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        if ($wp->request == 'your-page-here'){
            echo your_function_with_php_code();
            exit;
        }
    }
});

function your_function_with_php_code() {
    ob_start();
    echo 'This is a custom php page!';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

**3. Do not do this**

Your third and worst option is to create a PHP file in the same directory WordPress is installed to (probably htdocs)...  This is unmaintainable, so please don't do this.

Comment: Thank you! I did it with a Childtheme and Templates for each Page :)